# How to return the result of an Azure Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-functions

I'm starting with Azure Functions. I have the following code:

```
module.exports = function (context, req) 
    {
        context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

        context.log(context.req.body.videoId)
        if (context.req.body.videoId =! null) 
        {
            context.log('inicia a obtener comentarios')

             const fetchComments = require('youtube-comments-task')

            fetchComments(req.body.videoId)
            .fork(e => context.log('ERROR', e), p => {                   
                        context.log('comments', p.comments)
                        })        

             context.res = { body: fetchComments.comments }
        }
        else {
            context.res = {
                status: 400,
                body: "Please pass a videoId on the query string or in the   request body"
            };
        }
        context.done();
};
```

How can I return the JSON that fetchComments returns?

Comment: I haven't made any Functions with Node.js, but maybe you could move the `context.res = ...` and `context.done();` to the callback function where you log the comments?

Comment: i've tried, but the result is the same

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Move assigning `context.res` and call to `context.done` to promise callback. Set `Content-Type` to `application/json` in the headers. Based on your code, something like

```
if (context.req.body.videoId =! null) {
  context.log('inicia a obtener comentarios')
  const fetchComments = require('youtube-comments-task')

  fetchComments(req.body.videoId)
    .fork(e => context.log('ERROR', e), p => {                   
       context.log('comments', p.comments);
       context.res = { 
         headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
         body: p.comments 
       };
       context.done();
    });
}
else {
  context.res = {
    status: 400,
    body: "Please pass a videoId on the query string or in the request body"
  };
  context.done();
}
```

Comment: i've tried. 

fetchComments(req.body.videoId)
.fork(e => context.log('ERROR', e), p => {                   
        context.log('comments', p.comments);
         context.res = { body: p.comments };
         context.done();
          }) 

but the result is the same. i only go status 200 Ok. no body content.